# Add filter to SMTP Client

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I am using the following code to send emails using SendGrid:

```
        string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridUser"];
        string passWord = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridKey"];

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", Convert.ToInt32(587));
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, passWord);
        smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;

        smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
```

And now I need to add an additional filter setting and now sure how to add it.  The filter that I need to include is to included the enabling of "bypass list management".  How do I add that?

Comment: What's up with `Convert.ToInt32(587)`? That's already an Int32 literal.

Comment: The documentation describes [how to set a filter using a particular header.](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/smtp-filters) Have you read the documentation? Tried to set the header? What was the result?

Comment: @mason Not sure how to use a JSON header with this call.

Comment: A header is a string. JSON is just a string. I suggest you make an attempt at setting the header. If you get stuck, show what you've tried as a [mcve] and clearly explain which part of it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

To send filters, such as ["bypass list management"](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/index-suppressions#bypass-list-management), you should send them as a JSON string as part of the `X-SMTPAPI` header. You can read more about [building an `X-SMTPAPI` header here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/building-an-x-smtpapi-header).

An example `X-SMTPAPI` header that bypasses list management might look like:

```json
{
  "filters": {
    "bypass_list_management": true
  }
}
```

You can add this to the headers of the `mailMsg` like so:

```cs
mailMsg.Headers.Add("X-SMTPAPI", jsonString);
```